# How can I connect to a database on another virtual machine through WCF?

Tags: sql, database, wcf, authentication

We've got a WCF service that used to connect to a database on the same machine. We have since moved both the database and the service to different machines (both virtual machines on the same physical box that can see one another).

I've set up a standard windows login on the database machine (WCFServiceLogin), added a database login on the database pointing to that windows login, added a SQL user to the database that points to that database login, and changed the connection string in the Visual Studio project settings:

```
Data Source=NewServer;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=True;
UserID=WCFServiceLogin;Password=password
```

When I try to make a call that touches the database, I get this error:

> Login failed for user 'NT
>   AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.

How can I get my WCF operations to successfully read from a database on a new machine, using the correct login?

**Update**

I think I've managed to get a little farther. I created a WCFServiceLogin login on the machine that the service is on with the same password as its counterpart on NewServer. I then set my WCF service to run as this login, and changed the SQL login to use Windows Authentication, and removed the User ID and Password from the connection string. Lastly, I ran exec sp_grantlogin 'NewServer\WCFServiceLogin'.

I'm now getting this error, though:

> Cannot open database "MyDB" requested
>   by the login. The login failed. Login
>   failed for user
>   'NewServer\WCFServiceLogin'.

So it seems like it's trying to log in with the right user, it's just failing to do so.

Comment: Is the WCF service running from inside IIS?

Comment: Is WCFServiceLogin in AD? If not, the WCF machine may have difficulty using this login.

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates the service is not using the WCFServiceLogin credential.

If the WCF service running under IIS, make sure the application pool has the identity set to WCFServiceLogin.  Otherwise, make sure the app/service running the WCF service is running under the WCFServiceLogin credential.

Alternatively, inside the code you could imperonate the user, however this hinders maintainability.

Also: the username/password in the connection string will not work if WCFServiceLogin is a windows account, you have to keep the integrated security.

EDIT:

To clarify, integrated authentication is using a windows (active directory domain or machine) account to login.  The connection string uses the integrated=true as you had in your question. You should not have the username and password fields in this case.  The connection will use the credentials that the process is running as.

The problem with this solution for your question is that the service (process) is not able to run as the WCFServiceLogin, because it is specific to the database server machine.  This could only really work if the user account was in active directory.

A possible solution is to create a SQL authentication account - that is an account created in SQL and does not map to a windows username.  Specify the username and password in the connection string, and remove the integrated security=true.

If you don't have an active directory then SQL authentication will work.

I hope this clarifies the difference and why integrated security will not work with a machine user account.

UPDATE:

The error message indicates the DB is still unable to authenticate using the newserver\WCFServiceLogin account, as it is on the other machine.

Comment: The service is self hosted. It is running in a Windows Service under the Network Service account. Do I have to change that? It's on a different machine than the database, so I can't change it to NewServer\WCFServiceLogin. Or can I?

Comment: I don't think you can impersonate a windows user on a different machine, usually this would be done using active directory.  I think the best way forward would be to use a SQL account with user/pass.

Comment: Isn't that what I'm doing by specifying the credentials in the connection string? I don't understand the bit about the integrated security. Does that mean I can't use windows authentication and instead must specify a username and password in SQL?

Comment: See the updated answer, it was a bit long to put in a comment. :) Let me know if you are still having issues.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help. I created a login on my database with a username and a password. I then used this connection string: Data Source=NewServer;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=False;User ID=SQLTest;Password=thepassword. Doing so yields this error: Login failed for user 'SQLTest', with unfortunately no further information anywhere in the exception. I did not change the account that the service was running in. Does that matter?

Comment: The connection string looks fine.  You can test logging in with teh SQLTest user with SQL Server Management Studio by selecting SQL Authentication Mode. That will make sure the credentials are correct.  Make sure remote connections are enabled as well.

Comment: Remote connections are enabled. Unfortunately, I don't have SQL Management Studio on the machine with the services. Any other suggestions to diagnose the problem?

Comment: Make sure the database setting for security is mixed mode, not just windows authentication.  Also you can try to login to the database server if you are using Visual Studio 2010.  Go to the Data menu, Transact-SQL Editor, New Query Connection and try to connect using the SQL credentials.